# Numpy/Tensorflow: Multiplying each depth-wise vector of 3D tensor by a 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

I have a **4x4x256** tensor and a **128x256** matrix. I need to multiply each **256-d** depth-wise vector of the tensor by the matrix, such that I get a **4x4x128** tensor as a result.

Working in Numpy it's not clear to me how to do this. In their current shape it doesn't look like any variant of `np.dot` exists to do this.  Manipulating the shapes to take advantage of broadcasting rules doesn't seem to provide any help.  `np.tensordot` and `np.einsum` may be useful but looking at the documentation is going right over my head.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.einsum` to do this operation. An example with random values:

```
a = np.arange(4096.).reshape(4,4,256)
b = np.arange(32768.).reshape(128,256)
c = np.einsum('ijk,lk->ijl',a,b)
print(c.shape)
```

Here, the `subscripts` argument is: `ijk,lk->ijl`
From your requirement, `i=4, j=4, k=256, l=128`
The comma separates the subscripts for two operands, and the subscripts state that the multiplication should be performed over the last subscript in each tensor (the subscript `k` which is common to both the tensors).

The tensor subscript after the `->` states that the resultant tensor should have the shape `(i,j,l)`. Now depending on the type of operation you are performing, you might have to retain this subscript or change this subscript to `jil`, but the rest of the `subscripts` remains the same.